# How to make VS code recognize the repo's own linting setting

Tags: eslint, visual-studio-code

I could not find this setting. Maybe I use wrong keywords for search. Please correct me if I do so.

I work on different repos and each of them has their own eslint setting. But my VScode uses its global settings on each of them, and causes my code not pass the pipeline at the end.

How can i change the VScode settings? So it can see the folder has its own eslint file and starts using those instead of the default.

Comment: try workspace settings, which can override global user settings. workspace settings are specific to a folder and you can verify if you already have workspace settings by looking file `.vscode/settings.json` in concerned repo

Comment: Thank you, Jahan! I separated the workplaces, this way VScode is able to keep the setting separately.

Comment: @moms Please don't vandalize your questions, you did the same thing with https://stackoverflow.com/q/63151742/691711.  If you want to delete your question, you can click the delete button under the question.  Looking at the edit history, you even did that.  Why did you then undelete the question?